# jQuery.eCalendar() - only highlight onclick date

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

The current code I have now highlight every date that I clicked. I only want to highlight that specific clicked date. How can I do this correctly? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

```
var mouseClickEvent = function () {
    $(".c-event-item").hide();
    var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
    $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
    $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').addClass('c-event-onclick');
    $('div.c-event-item[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
};
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/51pf3rqv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `c-event-onclick` class first before adding it. So, this code should work:

```
var mouseClickEvent = function () {
    $(".c-event-item").hide();
    $(".c-event").removeClass('c-event-onclick'); // <== add this
    var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
    $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
    $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').addClass('c-event-onclick');
    $('div.c-event-item[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
};
```

Comment: It works like charm! But why isn't it working when I clicked on today's date?

Comment: You might want to add c-event class to the today's date as well.

Comment: I have no clue where to add c-event-onclick on today's date. I tried with $('div.c-today.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').addClass('c-event-onclick'); but it's not working.

Comment: What I mean is add `c-event` class to your today cell in DOM. And no need for any change in JS.

Comment: I already did add `c-event` in DOM. It supposed to change to red colour once I clicked on it but it remains blue.

Comment: That's probably because your `c-today` class overrides its style. Inspect it with your browser and see if you can make `e-event-onclick` style the highest priority.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!